# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\Client" not found in C:\wamp64\www\prac1\mongoxd.php on line 10

Tags: php, mongodb, apache, wamp

I am trying to make a website where users have to log in, through the password and username fields. If the username and password are correct, the website has to show a message saying that the log has been successful. It is important that the password field is vulnerable to nosql injections, like "[$ne]=1". The goal is that if I put a user that exists and the nosql injection, I should get the message "the log was successful".

The problem is that I have to connect to a mongoDB database, but it tells me that I am not connected correctly. I get the following error:

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "MongoDB\Client" not found in C:\wamp64\www\prac1\mongoxd.php on line 10

( ! ) Error: Class "MongoDB\Client" not found in C:\wamp64\www\prac1\mongoxd.php on line 10

What is wrong with my code? In case you are wondering, I have installed the mongodb extension in PHP.

```
<?php


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    
    $mongoClient = new \MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");

 
    $collection = $mongoClient->Users->users_info;
    $cursor = $collection->find(['Name' => $_GET['Name'], 'Password' => $_GET['Password']]);

   
    if ($cursor->count() > 0) {
        echo "Log successful";
    } else {
        echo "Error";
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Login (Inseguro)</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
        <label for="username">User name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" required><br>

        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" name="password" required><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you installed MongoDB\Client?

Be aware that if you installed via Composer like so:

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

You should include an autoload like this:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Other than that, there's no need for an extra backslash before the word "new", you can change it like:

```
$mongoClient = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

Also, be sure that the extension is enabled on your php.ini file

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you installed the MongoDB\Client using composer, you should add

   require 'vendor/autoload.php';

in the top most of the file

2. If you downloaded a zip file or installed by downloading, you may use

   require 'directory_of_MongoDB/the_class_file_name.php';

Your error means all though you might have MongoDB installed but it has not been included in the file being executed. In this case, consider point 2 above if you didn't install it via composer. Thanks